# Issue redirecting to the home page using JAVA and Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, redirect

I'm facing an issue as to redirecting my website to a certain specific URL...

to better explain, I'm adding an auto refresh meta to the top of my jsp that refreshes the web page every 15 minutes, the only problem here is that when the 15 minutes are over, instead of refreshing the same page (thus calling the same servlet to recalculate what needs to be recalculated) it redirects to the home page!(defined in xml as login.jsp)

Now I've tried to debug the code to see which part is redirecting to the home page but it seems that it's no power of my own! it's probably something Tomcat is doing that I'm not aware of. It already happened to me before and the solution was to add an attribute to the session scope `session.setAttribute("User",user);`
but not this time...

To support my point(It's not a session problem), here's a portion of the code directly extracted from the page source code after redirection

```
<header>
            <h1>WelcomeTV</h1>
        </header>
        <section>
                <form action="Login" method="post">
                    <ul>
                        <li><label for="username">Username</label></li>
                        <li><input type="text" name="user" id="username" placeholder="Your Username" value="wtv_administratifs"></li>
                        <li><label for="password">Password</label></li>
                        <li><input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Your Password"></li>
                        <li><input type="submit" value="Log in"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="reset_pwd"><a href="mailto:EUS_EMEA_Reporting@Dell.com?subject=Service Desk BI Tool - Password Reset">Reset your password</a></p>
                    <p class="change_pwd"><a href="http://10.84.18.51:8080/SpagoBI/ChangePwdServlet?start_url=http://10.84.18.51:8080/SpagoBI">Change your password</a></p>




                </form>
        </section>
```

You can see that the value is filled, and in my jsp the value is taking ${sessionScope.username} so this proves that the session is still valid

Please help me? if it's not clear please let me know, I'll try to make myself clearer.

Comment: Can we have some code to work with?

Comment: Looks like your session is expiring

Comment: @shinjw I doubt that, since when the login page is loaded, the user name field is still filled with the last session value... (ex if you logged into my web site, after 15 mins Tomcat will redirect you to the login page with the username field filled with shinjw)

Comment: @RickyA I'm confused as to which code should I share with you? It's all proper to the company's need... as to the rest well it's only setting attributes onto the session scope or the request scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, This is embarrassing... It seems the little problem I have has nothing to do with the previous one I resolved with an input into the session scope.

The issue was simply that the URL after logging into my website stays //Context/Login (HTTP POST ><) and with the meta auto refresh, it does not refresh the servlet called after the login, it actually refreshes the same URL displayed above => Login and thus redirects me to the login page...

Issue resolved by adding

`<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="900;URL=http://10.84.18.53:8080/Welcome_TV/display">` which is the servlet that needs to do all the recalculation.

Issue resolved, thank you for you comments and terribly sorry for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Set up your session config in your web xml to -1 if you do not want it to expire

Comment: it's already set to 60 minutes `<session-config> 
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>`